# Webpack: Is it possible to load svg with the file-loader? If yes, how?

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I want to load my svg via the `file-loader` with webpack. Is this even possible and if yes, how do I do that.

webpack.config.js

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name:'[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'img/',
      publicPath: '../',
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fault, it was because I never used the svg in my project so it never got compiled. Now the file-loader compiles my svg too.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Just imported svg as html and then injected to your template as component. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to have my html and svg graphic in two separate files.